# Function __annotations__ dict has positional-only arguments go after positional-or-keyword ones

Tags: python, annotations, python-3.8, function-parameter

Arguments of a Python 3.8 function are defined in particular order: *positional-only, mixed, keyword-only*.

But `__annotations__` define them in a different order: *mixed, positional-only, keyword-only*.

```py
>>> def func(b: int, a: str, /, c: bool, *, e: float, d: tuple):
...     pass
... 
>>> func.__annotations__
{'c': 'bool', 'b': 'int', 'a': 'str', 'e': 'float', 'd': 'tuple'}
```

Is that behavour intentional? Or is it just implementation detail and no specific order is guaranteed at all?

I would expect native order of arguments that matches function definition. That would have made some things a lot easier IMO...

Comment: They *could* have theoretically made the order consistent since dictionaries are ordered by insertion order in Python 3.8, but in general, I wouldn't assume that the order of a dictionary is significant unless that's explicitly documented.

Comment: Annotations predate ordered dictionaries though, so that's probably remnant behavior from before and they didn't deem it necessary to "fix".